# Como centrar un menus

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Hola a todos estoy tratando de centrar estos div pero no he podido y apreciaria mucho su ayuda.

```css
* 
{
 margin:0px;
 padding: 0px;
}   
#header 
{
 margin:auto;
 width:600px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 
}   
ul, ol 
{
 list-style:none;
 
}   
.nav 
{
 width:800px;
 margin:0 auto;
 
}
 
.nav > li
 {
 float:left;
 
}   
.nav li a 
{
 background-color:#ffe3a4;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:10px 12px;
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 
}   
.nav li a:hover 
{
 background-color:#8a92a6;
}   
.nav li ul 
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 min-width:140px;
 
}   
.nav li:hover > ul 
{
 display:block;
}   
.nav li ul li 
{
 position:relative;
}   
.nav li ul li ul 
{
 right:-140px;
 top:0px;
 
}
.contenedor{
 margin:auto;
 width:90%;
 padding-top: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 /*padding-bottom: 10px;
 width: 90%;
 margin: 20 auto;
 padding-top: 5px;*/
}
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 font: normal 18px/3 "Fira Sans", "Heveltica Neue", sans-serif;
 background: #3aafab;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
}

h1{
 text-align: center;
}

.form-registro{
 width: 95%;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: auto;
 background:white;
 border-radius: 7px;
 
}
h2.titulo{
 background: deepskyblue;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-top-left-radius: 7px;
 border-top-right-radius: 7px;
 border-bottom: 5px solid crimson;
}
h2{
 background: deepskyblue;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-top-left-radius: 7px;
 border-top-right-radius: 7px;
 border-bottom: 5px solid crimson;
}

.contenedor-input{
 padding: 10px 30px;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

input{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 15px;
 font-size: 16px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.input-48{
 width: 48%;
}

.input-100{
 width: 100%;
}

select
{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.btn-enviar{
 background: crimson;
 color: white;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 10px 40px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-enviar:active{
 transform: scale(1.05);
}
.contenido{
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display:grid; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title id="titulo"></title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reg.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/menu.css">
 <script src = "../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/menu1.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/menu.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
 <div class="contenedor">
  <ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="#">Capitan</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="../html/registro.html" id = "addCap">Agregar</a></li>
     <li><a href="../html/modificar_capitan.html">Modificar</a></li>
     <li><a href="../html/eliminar_capitan.html">Eliminar</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="">Congregación</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="../html/registro_congregacion.html">Agregar</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Eliminar</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Modificar</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="">Centro de salida</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="../html/registro_centro_salida.html">Agregar</a></li>
     <li><a href="../html/eliminar_centro_salida.html">Eliminar</a></li>
     <li><a href="../html/modificar_centro.html">Modificar</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="">Territorios de predicación</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="../html/registro_territorios.html">Agregar</a></li>
     <li><a href="../html/eliminar_territorio.html">Eliminar</a></li>
     <li><a href="../html/modificar_territorio.html">Modificar</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="">Predicacion</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="../html/territorio_predicado.html">Registrar territorio predicado</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Visualizar territorios predicados</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="main">
  <div class="contenido" id="contenido">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda

Comment: ¿Centrar verticalmente u horizontalmente? Existen ya preguntas con solución en el sitio para ambos casos. ¿Qué has investigado al respecto? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de centrar, todo depende del modelo de caja escogido. Hay un montón y la forma de llamarlos es usando la propiedad `display`, te voy a explicar algunas formas de centrado, dependiendo del tipo de `display` escogido.

**La forma más conocida** son los margenes automáticos, para centrar **bloques.** Ejemplo:

```
.center_block{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Esto hace que los margenes laterales, cubran el espacio sobrante entre el bloque y su contenedor hacia los lados.

**La segunda forma** conocida es usando **bloques en linea**, estos se comportan como si fueran textos por lo que aplicar un alineamiento textual al centro los afecta. Sin embargo el alineamiento se lo debemos aplicar a su padre contenedor, sino no dará resultado:

```
.ancestro_contenedor{
   text-align: center
}

.ancestro_contenedor .bloque_en_linea{
   display: inline-block; 
}
```

**La forma más novedosa** es usar el modelo **flexbox**, este tiene varias propiedades de alineación, la que es para centrar horizontalmente es **`justify content`**, esta también se aplica al contenedor del elemento a centrar, así:

```
.ancestro_contenedor{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Hay otros más, como el uso de `display: table, grid` o combinandolas con la propiedad `transform` y/o la "función CSS" `calc` son algo más complejas e innecesarias de saber para tu caso, si quieres saber más, revisa este link:

- [Blog de Css en español: centrar al centro (16 maneras)](https://escss.blogspot.com.co/2012/05/centrando-al-centro-con-css-16-maneras.html)

---

Habiendo dicho lo anterior, en tu caso esta afectando mucho el que estés dándoles un tamaño de ancho a los contenedores y elementos anidados, así como que al contenedor ancestro le estas aplicando un ancho de 600px y al hijo 800px, causando desbordamiento. También hay una mezcla de distintos modelos de caja, `inline-block`, `block`, incluso `grid` (que es una propiedad experimental, aun no estandar) y aparte usas las técnicas de centrados contrarias a sus modelos de caja como por ejemplo `margin: 0 auto;` para centrar bloques en linea, pero no el `text-align` y mezclarlos con `floats`, en fin, un enredo jejeje corrigiendo lo anterior sería así:

```css
* 
{
 margin:0px;
 padding: 0px;
}   
#header 
{
 margin:auto;
 /* no le des un tamaño más pequeño que el contenido width: 600px; */
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 
}   
ul, ol 
{
 list-style:none;
}   
.nav 
{
 /*estas dos propiedades no hacen falta width:800px;*/
 margin:0 auto;
 display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 
.nav > li
 {
}   
.nav li a 
{
 background-color:#ffe3a4;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:10px 12px;
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 
}   
.nav li a:hover 
{
 background-color:#8a92a6;
}   
.nav li ul 
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 min-width:140px;
 
}   
.nav li:hover > ul 
{
 display:block;
}   
.nav li ul li 
{
 position:relative;
}   
.nav li ul li ul 
{
 right:-140px;
 top:0px;
 
}
.contenedor{
 margin: auto;
 width:90%;
 padding-top: 5px;
 /*aqui no sería display: inline-block; sino:*/
  display: block;
}
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 font: normal 18px/3 "Fira Sans", "Heveltica Neue", sans-serif;
 background: #3aafab;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
}

h1{
 text-align: center;
}

.form-registro{
 width: 95%;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: auto;
 background:white;
 border-radius: 7px;
 
}
h2.titulo{
 background: deepskyblue;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-top-left-radius: 7px;
 border-top-right-radius: 7px;
 border-bottom: 5px solid crimson;
}
h2{
 background: deepskyblue;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-top-left-radius: 7px;
 border-top-right-radius: 7px;
 border-bottom: 5px solid crimson;
}

.contenedor-input{
 padding: 10px 30px;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

input{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 15px;
 font-size: 16px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.input-48{
 width: 48%;
}

.input-100{
 width: 100%;
}

select
{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.btn-enviar{
 background: crimson;
 color: white;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 10px 40px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-enviar:active{
 transform: scale(1.05);
}
.contenido{
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: grid; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title id="titulo"></title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reg.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/menu.css">
 <script src = "../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/menu1.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/menu.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
 <div class="contenedor">
  <ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="#">Capitan</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="../html/registro.html" id = "addCap">Agregar</a></li>
     <li><a href="../html/modificar_capitan.html">Modificar</a></li>
     <li><a href="../html/eliminar_capitan.html">Eliminar</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="">Congregación</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="../html/registro_congregacion.html">Agregar</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Eliminar</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Modificar</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="">Centro de salida</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="../html/registro_centro_salida.html">Agregar</a></li>
     <li><a href="../html/eliminar_centro_salida.html">Eliminar</a></li>
     <li><a href="../html/modificar_centro.html">Modificar</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="">Territorios de predicación</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="../html/registro_territorios.html">Agregar</a></li>
     <li><a href="../html/eliminar_territorio.html">Eliminar</a></li>
     <li><a href="../html/modificar_territorio.html">Modificar</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="">Predicacion</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="../html/territorio_predicado.html">Registrar territorio predicado</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Visualizar territorios predicados</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="main">
  <div class="contenido" id="contenido">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Igual no te preocupes, hay tantos modelos y formas, que aveces uno se enreda al principio y es muy complicado ir al paso de los experimentados, sin embargo poco a poco se van adquiriendo las habilidades, lo importante es que tengas claro como funcionan los modelos de caja y que propiedades y atributos aplican o no, según el modelo seleccionado.

Comment: Gracias, mañana intentaré lo q me dices